# Disappearing Ajaxmin.dll file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, ajaxmin, bin-folder

I've been using Ajax controls for over a year in my asp.net project.

Recently I suddenly started getting the error "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxMin, Version=4.97.4951.28478" when I ran the project.  After some investigation I discovered this can be caused by a missing Ajaxmin.dll file. I located the file and copied it into my project's Bin folder where the AjaxControlToolKit.dll is.  All well and good.

Except that since then, the problem has re-occurred twice - everything works find for a while and then suddenly the dll vanishes from the folder and I get the error again.  I can fix it ok by copying it back in.  But what would cause a DLL just disappear from my project's Bin folder?

Comment: As an update.  This kept occurring for a few days, but then resolved itself.  I have no idea why.